# ajax php GET/POST without refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, get

I need to execute the following code, without refreshing the page... this code already includes ajax but where am I going wrong with getting it to execute without refreshing the page....? the .vote class is attatched to an anchor in my index.php file, and I need this all to still work when the anchor is clicked if possible. Re-coding this to perform on a button click would not be ideal.

```
$(".vote").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var eData = $(this).attr("data-options");
    var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&' + eData ;
    var parent = $(this);

    if(name=='up')
    {
       $(this).fadeIn(200).html('');
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "up.php",
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
             parent.html(html);
          }
       });
    }
    else
    {
       $(this).fadeIn(200).html('');
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "down.php",
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
             parent.html(html);
          }
       });
    }
});
```

here is the html from my index.php

```
<div id="main">
<div id="left">
<span class='up'><a href="" class="vote" name="up" data-options="key1=<?php echo $mes_id1;?>&key2=<?php echo $mes_id2;?>"><img src="up.png" alt="Down" /></a></span><br />
<?php echo $totalvotes1; ?><br />
</div>
<div id="message">
    <?php echo $message1; ?>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
<div id="main">
<div id="right">
<br />
<?php echo $totalvotes2; ?><br />
<span class='down'><a href="" class="vote" name="down" data-options="key1=<?php echo $mes_id1;?>&key2=<?php echo $mes_id2;?>"><img src="down.png" alt="Down" /></a></span>
</div>
<div id="message">
    <?php echo $message2; ?>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: so basically you guys are saying there is an easy answer and I need to research it more than I already have...?

Comment: re-coding this to work with a button click involves changing a class and adding a button tag. also, if you dont want to refresh the page, then don't link the anchor to anything...

Comment: the anchor isn't linked to anything. and I dont want it to be a button

Comment: You, uhh, can style an <i> tag to act like a table given enough time, so it's not like much of that matters. also, have you ensured that *the document is ready beforehand?*

Comment: no there is no $(document).ready(function() .... is that necessary...?

Comment: Try preventing the default action `$(".vote").click(function(e){e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Well, you can't hook into events on something that doesnt exist yet. but really, add your script tag at the *end* of the page. faster loading times, and all (people say this is bad practise, but it's what jQuery and twitter recommend, and it makes logical sense...)

Comment: added a document.ready, it still works the same way as it did before and refreshes the page. tried Musa's answer, that didn't work either.

Comment: @PatrickLawler what is your `<a>` tag even pointed to? I don't see anything refreshing in what you posted.

Comment: I just posted the html with the <a> tag above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either enclose your code with `$(document).ready(function() {});`, or stick your code at the end of the `<body>` tag. Personally, instead of making the browser parse synchronous javascript before the DOM has loaded (in the `<head>` section), I stick it near the end. This is also what Bootstrap recommends.

Without a DOM loaded, there are no elements created for jQuery to register Events with, and so your code literally sits there doing nothing after being parsed.

Aside from that, the `.click()` function is executed on click. It doesn't matter what element it's bound to. If it's clickable, it's executable.

Also to answer your question properly: `<a href="">` will refresh the page. You want to use
`<a href="#">`. This, however, will make you jump to the top of the page. You could also define a `<label>` and use `#labelname` instead to avoid this. Or just don't use `href` at all. It's not needed.

Also, a little trick for echoing variables into HTML is to use `<?= $var ?>`

Comment: thank you all. this is all very helpful in terms of refreshing my memory of the basics of javascript, which I clearly need. I have now included a $(document).ready(function() but in terms of getting this script to perform without reloading the page I still need help...

Comment: I just posted it above, sorry

Comment: omg thank you...so much. the # stops the refresh I don't know how I forgot that. getting closer here...

Comment: so now the page doesn't reload and the php executes when the <a> is clicked, but the results aren't displayed unless I manually refresh the page. I'm gonna go research that myself now... unless somebody here would know a quick answer to how to get the results to display without refreshing it manually

Comment: @PatrickLawler Good to know you got it working (well, aside from the ajax). Remember: on stackoverflow, we like concise code snippets, but we also like them complete.

Comment: sorry! and thanks for everybody putting up with me... new to stackflow, and relatively new to coding... feel like huge n00b

Comment: @PatrickLawler and since there's a checkmark there and this answered the question, do you mind accepting it? :)

Comment: are you saying I should just <?php echo $var; ?> to get the results to display in my html?

Comment: @PatrickLawler no, you should fetch the results from some kind of API (return a json object, for example, after posting, so you can parse it)